# Regularly Http requests for update database

Tags: c#, sql, http

I need to create a new project, that have to regularly perform `Http` requests for new data.Than that data needs to be inserted into Database. It has to be performed every `30` second.
Can someone help me please, to show right way, or post some link, where I can find about it.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: if 1 min is acceptable, then google for "cron"

Answer (score 0):

You can create the windows service with System.Timers.Timer for frequently handle the webrequest and web response.